# Extension method to Order children alphanumerically in a tree-like generic list

Tags: c#, linq, generics, tree, extension-methods

The idea is to make extension method for sorting children (children's children and so on) of **any** tree like list (that has parent-child structure listed in example).
Also it is important to say that the property to sort by is only known durring runtime (as is a list itself).

The extension method should have something similar to this signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderChildren<T>(
this IEnumerable<T> source,
Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector,
Func<T, string> orderSelector)
{
...
}
```

Here is the example class to create a list:

```
public class Example
{
    public IEnumerable<Example> Children;

    public string Name;

    public int Id;

    public Example Parent;
}
```

And some mock data:

```
{
   ...
   var collection = MockUp();
   ...
}

private static IEnumerable<Example> MockUp()
{
    var rootCollection = new List<Example>();
    var firstLevelCollectionA = new List<Example>();
    var firstLevelCollectionB = new List<Example>();
    var secondLevelCollectionAA = new List<Example>();
    var secondLevelCollectionAB = new List<Example>();
    var secondLevelCollectionBA = new List<Example>();
    var secondLevelCollectionBB = new List<Example>();

    secondLevelCollectionAA.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlAA1"});
    secondLevelCollectionAA.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlAA2"});

    secondLevelCollectionAB.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlAB1"});
    secondLevelCollectionAB.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlAB2"});

    secondLevelCollectionBA.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlBA1"});
    secondLevelCollectionBA.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlBA2"});

    secondLevelCollectionBB.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlBB1"});
    secondLevelCollectionBB.Add(new Example() {Name = "SecondLvlBB2"});

    firstLevelCollectionA.Add(new Example() {Name = "FirstLvlA1", Children = secondLevelCollectionAA});
    firstLevelCollectionA.Add(new Example() {Name = "FirstLvlA2", Children = secondLevelCollectionAB});

    firstLevelCollectionB.Add(new Example() {Name = "FirstLvlB1", Children = secondLevelCollectionBA});
    firstLevelCollectionB.Add(new Example() {Name = "FirstLvlB2", Children = secondLevelCollectionBB});

    rootCollection.Add(new Example() {Name = "Root1", Children = firstLevelCollectionA});
    rootCollection.Add(new Example() {Name = "Root2", Children = firstLevelCollectionB});

    return rootCollection;
}
```

And then we need to call extension method `OrderChildren`, like so:

```
collection.OrderChildren(x => x.Children, x => x.Name)
```

So any suggestions on the body of this extension method?

Comment: +1 for ready-to-use code, but you should show a first try too.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question. I didn't figure out the way how to do it without some kind of reflection while keeping it sexy. The problem is mainly in setting the children property dynamically.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderRecursively<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>>  childrenExpression,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new Exception("source");

    var memberExpression = childrenExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new Exception("memberExpression");

    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo; 
    if(propertyInfo == null)
        throw new Exception("propertyInfo");

    var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "instance");
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (IEnumerable<T>), "param");

    var childrenSet = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, IEnumerable<T>>>(
        Expression.Call(instance, propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(), parameter),
        new[] {instance, parameter}).Compile();

    return OrderRecursivelyReflectionDarkness(
        source, 
        childrenExpression.Compile(), 
        keySelector, 
        childrenSet);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> OrderRecursivelyReflectionDarkness<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>  childrenSelector,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
    Action<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSetter)
{
    foreach (var parent in source.OrderBy(keySelector))
    {
        var children = childrenSelector(parent);
        if (children != null && children.Any())
        {
            var sortedChildren = children.OrderRecursivelyReflectionDarkness(
                childrenSelector,
                keySelector,
                childrenSetter);

            childrenSetter(parent, sortedChildren);
            yield return parent;
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to take care of memberExpression.Member as it can be field too.

It's also possible to avoid reflection, but it will be a little more awkward to use.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderRecursively<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>  childrenSelector,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
    Action<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSet)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new Exception("source");

    return OrderRecursivelyReflectionDarkness(
        source, 
        childrenSelector, 
        keySelector, 
        childrenSet);
}

//and usage
collection = collection.OrderRecursively(
x => x.Children, 
x => x.Name, 
(parent, sortedChildren) => parent.Children = sortedChildren).ToList();
```

Comment: Tnx for the response. I can't seem to get passed the FirstLvl. (with or without reflection I get 'new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<>(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<>(collection as System.Collections.Generic.List<>).Items[0].Children).Items' threw an exception of type 'System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugViewEmptyException')
and durring runtime second level children are empty.